# Like button not recording the data

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I have implemented a like button onto my view_post page, but the like's aren't been registered. When the button is clicked the page is redirected correctly but no likes are added.

**views**

```
def get_post(request, slug):
    try:
        post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist: 
        messages.error(request, 'This post does not exist.')
        post = None

    comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'mhpapp/view-post.html', {'post': post, 'comment_form': comment_form,})

def like_post(request, slug):
    template_name = 'view-post.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)

    liked = False

    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        messages.success(request, ("Thanks for the like...:-)"))
        liked = True

    return redirect('get_post', {'slug': slug,})
```

**urls**

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.get_post, name='viewpost'),
path('<slug:slug>/',views.like_post, name='likepost'),
```

**html**

```
 <strong>{{ post.total_likes }} Likes</strong>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'likepost' post.slug %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if request.user in post.likes.all %} 
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="post-id" value="{{ post.slug }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart-crack"></i></button>
        {% else %}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-0 custom-button" id="like" type="sumbit" name="post-id" value="{{ post.slug }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot set same path url for two views. django will loop into all url and take first which match the url path.

So in your case, your reversed url likepost always call `get_post` view I think.

Test like that:

```
path('view/<slug:slug>/', views.get_post, name='viewpost'),
path('like/<slug:slug>/',views.like_post, name='likepost'),
```

Comment: what exactly is the reason why we need to add extra urls when a like is submitted?

Comment: there are others ways to do this with only one view of course. I propose the most simple patch for your case

Comment: @DavidHenson Also this answer is partially true, my answer was fully which I deleted, here it should be `return redirect('viewpost', slug=slug)` instead of `return redirect('get_post', {'slug': slug,})`, otherwise you'll get `reverse` error as you already stated.